# While reading registers in lldb, how can two different addresses point to the same object?

Tags: xcode, pointers, lldb, cpu-registers

I have been trying to debug an issue, and have been using `lldb` to view the values stored in the registers to help.

I have a quick question:

```
(lldb) register read
General Purpose Registers:
       rbx = 0x0000618000a4fc60
       rbp = 0x00007fff5fbfc690
       rsp = 0x00007fff5fbfc670
       r12 = 0x0000000000000000
       r13 = 0x0000000101a53f00
       r14 = 0x00006000000c04d0
       r15 = 0x00007fff8468e0c0  libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend
       rip = 0x00007fff81a8faa1  Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
13 registers were unavailable.

(lldb) po $r13
<NSClipView: 0x101a53f00>

(lldb) po $rbx
<NSClipView: 0x101a53f00>
```

Why is it that even though the addresses at `$r13` and `$rbx` are totally different, when I `po` both, I end up with the same object?   Namely, the address stored at `$rbx` just prints out the value at `$r13`

I am thinking that the address at `$rbx` is an address to a pointer (because it starts with 0x00006xxxxx?), which once dereferenced, points to the object located at the address at `$r13`

So is `po` just smart, and recognizes when an address is a pointer address, and just automatically dereferences the pointer?

I also noticed there are 3 main types of addresses that I see.

```
 - 0x00006xxxxxxx 
 - 0x00007fffxxxx 
 - 0x000000xxxxxx
```

I have an idea of what is what-- like I noticed that the 0x00006xxxxxxx addresses seem to be pointers to my application's objects?

But I really am not sure of anything

Comment: This is actually rather intriguing. At a glance I don't think "po" has this "pointer-to-object" ability. To start, can you run a couple of things for me. First, do expr (void*)$rbx and expr (void*)$r13 to just read the pointer values there and see if they match reg read. Then, can you do a memory read -f A -c 10 at both pointer values? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Enrico, Thanks for reading!  I am currently really swamped at work and have switched off this issue.  We are releasing on Friday but next week I will come back to this and get you more information :)